# .net core mvc filter Stream was not readable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, filter

I want to record the value of the request and response

my action

```
public async Task<ResponseData<object>> litewxLogin([FromBody]LiteWxLoginInput input){
```

.....
}

filter:

```
  public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        string url = context.HttpContext.Request.Host + context.HttpContext.Request.Path + context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        string method = context.HttpContext.Request.Method;

        var result =  context.Result;  //This result is empty.

        //I wanted to read the body's data stream, but it also failed: "Stream is not readable



    }
```

**I can't get the stream to Iactionresult and response because the stream is read-only**

I sent it through the Bing Dictionary translation, and I hope you can read what I mean.

Thank you so much

Comment: If you want to record the request/response for debugging purposes, you could Fiddler: https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: 1. Do you mean `context.Result == null` ? Or you just think it as an "empty" one because you can't read the response?  2. What does your action method return ? Since you're adding an action filter, it's better to show us the action method. 3. I think it's much better to record the `context.Result` than read the hole stream.